# Van Kampen Theorem for a Certain Square

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Take a square with all the edges identifies. Choose a point $x$ on the boundary of this square. Take a small neighborhood $B_\epsilon(x)$ of this point. I want to compute $\pi_1(B_\epsilon(x) \setminus x,p)$ for any point $p \in B_\epsilon(x)$ that is in the interior of the square.

I tried using the van Kampen Theorem but couldn't seem to figure out what to choose for $U,V$. But I know something about wedge products of circles using the van Kampen Theorem so I tried the following:

Looking at my space, any neighborhood of $x$ "looks like" four half circles at a point, $x$, which are all identified. With a deformation retract, I should be able to turn this into a wedge of four circles at the point $x$. But then the fundamental group would be the free product on four generators. Would that be the correct approach?